# How to cancel a touchstart event when finger is moved

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a button that toggles on and off really responsively but doesn't toggle if the user then tries to scroll.

At first I just used a click event which allowed me to scroll without accidently pressing the button, however when trying to get the button to toggle there was too much of a lag.

This is the code I have tried to use:

```
$('.cut-btn').on('touchstart click', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('cut');
        });
        $('.cut-btn').on('touchcancel', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass('cut');
        });
```

I saw someone mention about a touchcancel but I am unsure of how it works.

Using the touchstart allowed me to get a quick response but if I accidently pressed on the button area and tried to scroll then it toggled the button on, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to listen for touchstart, touchmove, and touchend.

You need to save the coordinates from touchstart and compare them to the coordinates given by touchmove. If the Y scroll value (I'm assuming a standard vertical scrolling site here) is above a given threshold then you set a parameter to cancel the event and does so on touch end.

Simple example below, and on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fidih/1/edit).

```
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var activeTouches = {};

btn.addEventListener("touchstart", function touchStart(event) {
    var touches = event.changedTouches;

  for(var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
    // Store the event on touchstart
    activeTouches[ "$" + touches[i].identifier ] = {
      identifier: touches[i].identifier,
      pageY: touches[i].pageY,
      dY: 0,
      cancelled: false
    };
  }
});

btn.addEventListener("touchmove", function touchMove(event) {
    var touches = event.changedTouches;

    for( var i=0; i<touches.length; i++ ) {
        // Compare it on touchmove
        var theTouch = activeTouches[ "$" + touches[i].identifier ];
        theTouch.dy = touches[i].clientY - theTouch.pageY;

        if ( theTouch.dy > 30 || theTouch.dy < -30 ) {
            theTouch.cancelled = true;
        }
    }
});


btn.addEventListener("touchend", function touchEnd(event) {
    var touches = event.changedTouches;

  for(var i=0; i<touches.length; i++) {
    // Check it on touchend
    var theTouch = activeTouches[ "$" + touches[i].identifier ];      

    if ( theTouch.cancelled === true ) {
        console.log('Scrolled, do not submit');
    } else {
        console.log('OK, let us send that!')
    }
  }
});
```